# File Load Exception on application startup

Tags: vb.net, exception

My application has encountered a problem and needs to close.
Of course Microsoft is sorry for the inconvenience, but how am i supposed to debug my app?
Which dll fails to load?

The error report contains between others, `system.io.fileloadexception`

How do you handle situations like these?

Comment: Please provide more detail.  What is the exception's message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx).

This will allow you to see what assemblies are failing to load and why (this works for .NET dlls only).